# Windows 7 installation failed

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers, windows-installation

I have an ASUS X401A laptop. 
I attempt to install Windows 7 Home Premium 32 bit and all went fine, but i couldn't change the language, so i decided to reinstall it again. But this time i used Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit, and an error occurred after clicking the install now button, asking for a CD/DVD driver..

Im using an USB stick to install windows.. This pc only has 2 usb ports, one 2.0 and one 3.0 and no CD/DVD drive.

So why i was able to install the home premium but not the ultimate? I already tried to change usb slot while installing but nothing, still the same issue.
It's 2 days im trying to fix this, i hope someone can help, have a nice day!

Comment: use the USB 2.0 port , because Win7 has no USB 3.0 diver support out of box.

Comment: @magicandre1981 i already did these man, i used both usb, first 2.0 then 3.0.. I also enabled the pre boot mode for the 3.0 inside the bios..

Comment: add [USB 3.0 and AHCI/SATA drivers to the boot.wim](https://superuser.com/a/826191/174557)

Comment: @magicandre1981 i try with this one in some mins, i will let you know if it worked, thanks

Comment: @magicandre1981 thank you so much, it worked fine!